# sum and multiply of doubles and ints does not work

Tags: c, casting, int, double

I wrote this code in C:

```
 double x1 = 7.52, x2 = 7, x3 = 8;
 int m = 0;
 double sum = x1 + x2*m + x3*m*m;

 printf("%lf", m, sum);
```

but sum is always 0 no matter what the value of m that i changed..

why doesnt it make normal calculation ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your are printing `m` which is `int` with the `"%lf"` specifier which is for `double`.

And you are also passing more arguments to `printf()` than format specifiers, which means that you are not enabling compiler warnings, you should, specially if you are a beginner.

Change this

```
printf("%lf", m, sum);
```

to

```
printf("m   = %d\nsum = %f\n", m, sum);
```

and see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are printing the value of `m`  -

```
 printf("%lf", m, sum);
```

You have to print -

```
 printf("%lf",sum);
```